# Maximizing the chance of Instigate Psychic Duel being succesful?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization

I have been planning out a character which will be focused entirely on psychic duels instantly engaging whatever boss monster the group encounters in a psychic duel effectively stunning him while rest of the group deals with the minions.

What I want to ask is which feats/traits are useful for increasing the DC of [Instigate Psychic Duel](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/instigate-psychic-duel/)?

I am planning to make my character an Elan Psychic with Psychic duelist archetype.

Any non third party source is legal.

Comment: What levels are we looking at playing at?  We don't really have much in the way of spare feat/trait resources after making *Instigate Psychic Duel* a 1st level spell at levels 1-2.